# Finding out if an attribute is inherited

Tags: django, django-models

Is there any way to find out if a given attribute of a django model is inherited from the parent model? I don't know the model structure a-priori.

I'm currently retrieving all the parent models like this:

```
parents = mymodel._meta.get_parent_list()
```

And checking if the parent has the attribute like this:

```
isinherited = not getattr(parent, attributename, None) is None
```

But results are not consistent. Namely, with a model inheritance structure like

```
A <- B <- C
```

... and an attribute defined in B, I'm finding that all three models have the attribute (!).

B should have the attribute. C should have it too because it inherits it. But why does A have it?